# Android save ringtone small edit

Tags: android

Hello all i am using this code to display my soundboard and play sounds. I also wnat it to be able to save the sounds when the button is long clicked. I have got up to a stage where the button when long clicked will show a menu save as ringtone or notification and save the sound to the ringtones or notifications folder etc.

But the user then has to go and set it manually is there a way for the current rington to be overwrote as soon as the user clicks save as ringtone or notification.

Thanks.

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {


int selectedSoundId;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    final Resources res = getResources();

    //just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to backtoyou
    final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.PlaySound1, R.id.PlaySound2, R.id.PlaySound3, R.id.PlaySound4, R.id.PlaySound5,};
    final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.bentonirate, R.raw.bentonlong, R.raw.bentonshort, R.raw.ohjesuschrist, R.raw.ohjesuschristbenton, };

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
            //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
            //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                    player.reset();
                    try {
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };



    //set the same listener for every button ID, no need
    //to keep a reference to every button
    for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
        Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
        registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
        soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }



}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
 menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");
}
@Override   
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
 if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}   
  else if(item.getTitle()=="Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
  else {return false;}
 return true; 
}

public void function1(int id){  

    if 
     (savering(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

    }
    public void function2(int id){   
     if 
     (savenot(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }
    }



 //Save into Ring tone Folder

public boolean savering(int ressound){
 byte[] buffer=null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
 int size=50; 

 try {
   size = fIn.available();   
   buffer = new byte[size];   
   fIn.read(buffer);   
   fIn.close(); 
 } catch (IOException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;      } 

 String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";

 String filename="ohhh"+".ogg";


 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

 FileOutputStream save;
 try { 
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);   
  save.write(buffer);   
  save.flush();   
  save.close();   
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;  
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;
 }
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename))); 

 File k = new File(path, filename);   
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Benton Ringtone");   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "weee");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);    

 //Insert it into the database
 this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

 return true; 
}

 //Save in Notification Folder

public boolean savenot(int ressound){
 byte[] buffer=null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
 int size=0; 

 try {
   size = fIn.available();   
   buffer = new byte[size];   
   fIn.read(buffer);   
   fIn.close(); 
 } catch (IOException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;      } 

 String path="/sdcard/media/audio/notifications/";

 String filename="ohhh"+".ogg";

 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

 FileOutputStream save;
 try { 
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);   
  save.write(buffer);   
  save.flush();   
  save.close();   
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;  
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;
 }
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename))); 

 File k = new File(path, filename);   
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Benton Notification");   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "weee");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);    

 //Insert it into the database
 this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

 return true; 



}
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`RingtoneManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html). Use the static `setActualDefaultRingtoneUri` method. This allows you to set the default ringtone, notification and alarm sounds.